# Cannot mount windows share on boot using fstab

Tags: linux, mount, samba, cifs, fstab

I've got a problem on Debian 10.11 (but I think it's not only Debian related) with onboot mounting Windows share.

```
cifs-utils     2:6.8-2      amd64        Common Internet File System utilities
```

`cat /etc/fstab | grep share2`

gives

```
//10.100.0.204/share2   /home/share2    cifs    auto,vers=default,rw,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,noperm,gid=100,username=user1,password=passwordhard   0   0
```

When I type:
command `mount /home/share2` Works as expected.

dmesg gives me an errors:

```
[    5.045482] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    5.046471] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
```

I think that linux tries too early to mount samba shares.
What can I do about it?

I know that I can use crontab and:
`@reboot root sleep 15; mount /home/share2`
as workaround but I like resolving problems at source.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is indeed `samba` service is loading too fast.

It is possible to edit `samba` [service file](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux).

Add `Requires=<a service-name that need to be loaded prior to samba>`

This trick is the official pattern to control/manage/order `systemd` service loading.